# Invalid postback or callback argument exception is thrown if Event validation is enabled

Tags: asp.net

In the same aspx page, this gridview column works:

```
       <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" 
            itemstyle-cssclass ="SesnGV_SelectButton" ButtonType="Button">
```

But when I use the designer and convert it to a template field, resulting in this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="SesnGV_SelectButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="SesnGV_SelectButton" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

It gives the error:

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  
Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> 
in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
```

I've got a very similar control in another page, with no notation about enabling event validation, and it works fine.

Any suggestions on why this might be failing as a template field, but working as a straight command field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, **[EnableEventValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enableeventvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** is true, so you do not need to set it explicitly. Therefore, you can remove it safely.

In addition, if you bind data to **GridView** inside **Page_Load** event, you need to check  **IsPostBack** before binding.

Otherwise, **GridView is rebind again, and Button controls with different IDs will be created**. It causes `Invalid postback or callback argument` error.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ...;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed the problem.  Thanks! 

Hmm.. "Button controls with different ID's will be created". 

Meaning, perhaps, somewhere in the whole gridview create/send/return/receive/interpret cycle, the template button that was created is not recognized as the one that is returned...?

More black box asp.net behavior, I guess, however, I suppose that's the price of the automagic.  Again, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. ASP.Net is based on event model; control's ID must be same as original ID when postback. You might want to look at  ASP.Net MVC which is a lot more flexible than ASP.Net Web Form.